Synapse Notebook to Azure SQL Database connection issue
created  Linked service to Azure SQL database in Synapse Analytics that uses Authentication type "
System Assigned Managed Identity". Than referencing it in PySpark Notebook.  Method getConnectionString is used to get access token.
But its failing with error Message=Missing required property 'connectionstring' on AzureSqlLinkedservice
Below is the code and error message details
Code :
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://my_server_name.database.windows.net:1433;database=my_db_name;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"
token=TokenLibrary.getConnectionString("AzureSQLLinkedServiceName")

pushdown_query = "(SELECT col1 FROM my_table_name) as tbl"connectionProperties = {
 "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
 "accessToken" : token
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)

Error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary.getConnectionString. : com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenServiceClientResponseStatusException: Token Service returned 'Client Error' (400), with message: {"result":"DependencyError","errorId":"BadRequest","errorMessage":"[Code=400, Target=AzureSqllinkedservice, Message=Missing required property 'connectionstring' on AzureSqllinkedservice]. TraceId : 32b30cfe-512e-4d33-b423-279ac0ee933d | client-request-id : e232532f-dbe7-49c1-8111-316c65213981. Error Component : LSR"}


The error you are facing is because you are creating linked service with incorrect configuration to resolve it while creating linked service you have to select version as Legacy and also Authentication Should be System Assigned Managed Identity.

Execution:

